# is it possible to auto assign url in a web tab?

Tags: web-tab

I have a web tab created, the url of the web tab needs to different for different users.

For eg i have a field in users object which holds a url

When a particular user is logged in it needs to pick the url from his users record and use it for the web tab

Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like we can do it... there is an option of web tabs to use merge fields

Answer (score 2):

Goto setup -> Create -> tabs

click on new under web tabs

Choose a tab layout click next

choose Tab type as URL and fill in the name, label, tab style and content frame height

`Step 3. Enter the URL Details` screen

under Available Merge Fields

In my case i chose User Fields and then selected the field which holds the url, and copy the Merge Field Value and paste it into the box below Button or Link URL

clicking on the preview you should be able to preview the tab, configure the tab visibilty to various profiles.